# Get value of an api sveltejs

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to display the data of my api in the following way: {product.name}

```
<script>
import commerce from '$lib/commerce.js';


    const product = commerce.products.retrieve('prod_r2LM5QmejP5ZV1').then(product => console.log(product))
```

My result offers the json in the console, but I can not go further

Answer (score 1):

Since you can fetch the product into `product`, you can show it on the UI using properties. Data fetching can also be kind of refactored into its own functions:

```
<div>My product's name is {product.name}</div>

<script>
import commerce from '$lib/commerce.js';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
let product;
const getProducts = async () => {
  product = await commerce.products.retrieve('prod_r2LM5QmejP5ZV1')
}

onMount(asnyc ()=> { await getProducts(); });
</script>
```

For better UX you can display loading icons while stuff is being fetched. You can refer to https://dev.to/daveturissini/fetching-data-in-svelte-1jpn for more detailed example.